# How to make this slider show 2 quotes upon clicking on next and prev

Tags: javascript

Currently it doesn't work as intended.
I am trying to make the slide show show 2 slide in one line at any given time and when the user clicks on next and prev arrows then next 2 or previous two slides should show depending which one was clicked.
There can be total any number of slider but max two should show at a time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {color: cornflowerblue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
  <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
  <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
  <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>



<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  slides[slideIndex-2].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't run your code in codesandbox, can you give a [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to describe?

Comment: @rohiteb The answer below isn't  correct for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed a few things in your code, and should works fine, but I recommend you using any library with slideshows.

```
function showSlides(n) {
  if(n>=slides.length){
    n=0;
    slideIndex = 0
  } else if(n<0 && slides.length%2===0){
    n=slides.length-2;
    slideIndex = slides.length-2
  } else if(n<0 && slides.length%2===1) {
    n=slides.length-1;
    slideIndex = slides.length-1
  } 
  let slidesShow = Array.from(slides).slice(n,n+2);
  Array.from(slides).forEach(item=>{
    item.style.display='none'
  })
  for(let i= 0; i< slidesShow.length;i++){
    slidesShow[i].style.display = 'block'
  }
}

next.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  slideIndex = slideIndex+2
  showSlides(slideIndex);
})
prev.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  slideIndex = slideIndex-2
  showSlides(slideIndex);
})
```

Here is a workin fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1kL9t0g8/